# Start application in Zeppos simulator

Tags: javascript

I'm tryng develop apps for Zepp Os but facing trouble.
When a start a app using zeus dev the app section of simulator reconize the app, but i can't see the the "start" button to initialize the app, onlye "delete".

In the terminal log the console say "Connection closed"

See the in the images:

[Simulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY46O.png)

[Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycU2p.png)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of it sounds like the nodejs version is incompatible. Updating to version 16 LTS should fix it.